# I want same styling for borders like jpeg that I attached. My borders are coming up and down. I want to merge the borders like this image

Tags: html, css

[I am doing psd to html for this using bootstrap 3. I want same styles for borders. my problem is when I am giving border to container it is coming above that navigation active class border. My English is weak. It would be great if you can help me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPYdt.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Show your html and css with jsfiddle

Comment: there in no css and html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bhavesh_ei/6484tndu/ Just remove that toggle navigation. I dont know how to add media query in js fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bhavesh_ei/6484tndu/ updated html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to add in style may help you

```
.navbar-nav > li 
{
border-top: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.active 
{
border-top: 3px solid #d15962 !important;
}
```

Comment: just change that rgba(0,0,0,0) to rgba(0,0,0,1)..!! Thanks buddy for your help..:)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container-fluid.nav-bg {
    background: #BFDFDE none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
.container > .navbar-header
{
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
}
.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.nav > li:hover:before,
.active:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    background:#D15962;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid nav-bg">
     <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank">HOME <span> | </span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">ABOUT US <span> | </span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">SERVICES <span> | </span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">GALLERY <span> | </span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">CONTACT US <span> | </span></a></li>
                    </ul>
     
       </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
              </div>
    </div>
```

And the result:

[image: image of result]

Comment: Hello Mosh, I didnt see any changes. Can you share your screenshot?

Comment: @BhaveshChhatani I was updated my answer, image added.

Answer (score 0):

Used to this `css` and get your result as like you .

i m just modify your `css` file as like  this

```css
.container-fluid.nav-bg {
    background: #BFDFDE none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
.container > .navbar-header
{
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    margin:0 50px;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:solid 3px blue;
}

.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav > li.active:after, .nav > li:hover:after{
    content:"";
    border-top: 3px solid #D15962;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:-3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid nav-bg">
     <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank">HOME <span> | </span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">ABOUT US <span> | </span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">SERVICES <span> | </span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">GALLERY <span> | </span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">CONTACT US <span> | </span></a></li>
                    </ul>
     
       </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
              </div>
    </div>
```